How to Register File Type in Windows/OneDrive for Content Searching?
I want to be able to search the contents of yang files, which are plain text files, but Windows doesn't seem to understand that.  Is there a way to register file types so that Windows knows that it can do content searches on them?  Also, can I get content searching of the files in OneDrive as well?
